# Interop of C structure with Fortran

Tags: c, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

Let's say I have this C structure :

```
struct
{
    union
    {
        unsigned char *lpbData; /* data passed to XL */
        void* hdata;            /* data returned from XL */
    } h;
    long cbData;
} bigdata;
```

and that I have to "interop" it with Fortran. How can I do this ?

(I could create a Fortran structure containing a Union (my Fortran compiler knows the Union extension) but the Union cannot contain anything allocatable, nor a pointer ....)

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  From Fortran 2018, page 476.

*There is no Fortran type that is interoperable with a C structure type that contains a bit field or that contains a flexible array member. There is no Fortran type that is interoperable with a C union type.*

Comment: Then I don't understand what `VARIANT` the file `ipsxe2019-samples-win-20190327\compiler_f\COM\src\EXCEL.f90` (from https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/download/776976.html) refers to , as the `VARIANT` excel type is well-known to be C implement with a union ...

Comment: The word _variant_ appears twice in the Fortran 2018 standard, where it is used in its normal English language usage.  That is from page 573: _Another common variant is the argument ..._  Looks likes you need to read the Intel documentation to see if this is a vendor extension.